# Cannot Log in to Ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, gdm, login

I have a Dual Boot-up with **Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu**.

My Ubuntu 10.10 does not allow me to log in and says that the **GNOME power manager**

***has not been installed properly & asks me to contact the system administrator.***

However I'm sure that the my password is correct,because it worked perfectly fine until yesterday.How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a live cd, boot from this, and run a disk check on the ubuntu partition.

To do this, you need to first run `fdisk -l` from a root terminal, then once you know the location of the ubuntu partition, run `fsck /path/to_drive`.

Once the disk check is complete, you can restart your system (without the CD) and it should be working again.

Comment: OK.I'll Do that.But can you please tell me what could have gone wrong? I have never touched the root directory or any system files.I've been using Ubuntu for over 2 years and this is the first time I had to face this

Comment: Could be one of a billion reasons.  Hence the disk check, i am assuming that Roland thinks your system might be failing.

Comment: @Pavitar: it's not something you did wrong. It has happened to me before as well. It happens when the filesystem has a serious error and needs to be checked. what happens is the system starts in read only mode (I'm not sure what triggers that) and so gnome-power-manager has a serious problem, and you won't be able to login either.

Comment: [Roland Taylor](http://askubuntu.com/users/1992/roland-taylor) -- Hey I tried it but it does not let me run the Live CD. When I boot up with Ubuntu CD it takes me to a screen and then switches off my monitor.

Comment: @Pavitar: "takes you to a screen?" can you explain please?

Comment: [Roland Taylor](http://askubuntu.com/users/1992/roland-taylor) -- It takes me to a blank screen with the Ubuntu Theme on display with a small icon at the bottom.Like the first page to be seen on startup of Live CD and then it just puts my monitor off.Can there be any hardware issues as well? I have Windows7 running as dual boot up and it runs fine. I have 1GB of RAM,could this be an issue?

Comment: @Pavitar: When you start up the live cd, can you try turning off Kernel mode setting? (press any key when the CD is first inserted, then press the key for other options and disable KMS).

Comment: I tried reconfiguring Gnome Power manager by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-power-manager` and it worked. though your answer was helpful too. Thankyou.I have a little less reputation to vote up ur answer.So I have accepted it and marked it as correct.

Comment: @Pavitar: that's great you got it working ^^, and I'm glad you found the solution on your own :) - great learning experience.